# An error while using bundle install: nokogiri installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I am using ubuntu and when I use bundle install I get an error with nokogiri installation. How can I fix it?

gem_make.out :

```
At top level:
xslt_stylesheet.c:112:13: warning: ‘swallow_superfluous_xml_errors’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
  112 | static void swallow_superfluous_xml_errors(void * userdata, xmlErrorPtr error, ...)
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
linking shared-object nokogiri/nokogiri.so
Cleaning files only used during build.
rm -rf /home/domke89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ports/archives

current directory: /home/domke89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/bin/mkdir: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:202: .sitearchdir.-.nokogiri.time] Error 127

make install failed, exit code 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a similar question was handled on the Nokogiri Github, on [this issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/2034).

From the discussion it seems like you might have some issues with the Ruby and Rubygems configuration on your machine.